# How to derive ethereum address from Elliptic Curve secp256k1 - SHA256 Digest

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, public-key, google-cloud-kms

I am using google cloud key management service to generate and manage keys. I have generated the HSM key for **Asymmetric signing** using **Elliptic Curve secp256k1 - SHA256 Digest**. The public key is something as below -

```js
{
  pem: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n' +
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n' +
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n',
  algorithm: 'EC_SIGN_SECP256K1_SHA256',
  pemCrc32c: { value: '12345678' },
  name: 'PATH-TO-KEY-ON-KMS/cryptoKeyVersions/1',
  protectionLevel: 'HSM'
}
```

I am looking to derive Ethereum address from this so that I can fund the wallet and perform signing. For the same I have written a function as  below -

```js
const deriveEthAddress = async () => {
    const publicKey = await getPublicKey(); // this returns same key as show above snippet
    const address = keccak256(publicKey.pem);
    const hexAddress = address.toString('hex');
    return '0x' + hexAddress.toString('hex').substring(hexAddress.length - 40, hexAddress.length)
}
```

This function gives me ethereum checksum verified address, but not sure is it the correct way to do this. Is this solution correct or needs improvement?

**Example public key:**

```js
publicKey {
  pem: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
    'MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEeYRv0S7Zf5CNh5/APxiT6xoY+z521DHT\n' +
    'FgLdUPUP2e/3jkYDuZTbCHP8zEHm7nhG6AUOpJCbTF2J2vWkC1i3Yg==\n' +
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n',
  algorithm: 'EC_SIGN_SECP256K1_SHA256',
  pemCrc32c: { value: '41325621' },
  name: 'PATH-TO-KEY-ON-KMS/cryptoKeyVersions/1',
  protectionLevel: 'HSM'
}
```

And, ethereum address I am deriving is - `0x8aCd56527DfE9205edf7D6F1EB39A5c9aa8aaE3F`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not use the PEM encoded public key when determining the Keccak hash, but must apply the raw public key, i.e. the concatenation of the hex encoded x and y value.
This can be derived most easily from the PEM encoded key by converting it to a DER encoded key. The last 64 bytes of the DER encoded key correspond to the raw public key (at least for secp256k1, the elliptic curve used by Ethereum):

```js
var publicKey = {
  pem: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
  ...
}

// Export raw public key (without 0x04 prefix)
var x509pem = publicKey.pem;
var x509der = crypto.createPublicKey(x509pem).export({format: 'der', type: 'spki'});
var rawXY = x509der.subarray(-64);
console.log('Raw key: 0x' + rawXY.toString('hex')); // 79846fd12ed97f908d879fc03f1893eb1a18fb3e76d431d31602dd50f50fd9eff78e4603b994db0873fccc41e6ee7846e8050ea4909b4c5d89daf5a40b58b762
```

For your pem encoded public key the raw public key is (hex encoded):

```
79846fd12ed97f908d879fc03f1893eb1a18fb3e76d431d31602dd50f50fd9eff78e4603b994db0873fccc41e6ee7846e8050ea4909b4c5d89daf5a40b58b762
```

The Ethereum address derived from this is (hex encoded):

```
fd55ad0678e9b90d5f5175d7ce5fd1ebd440309d
```

or with checksum:

```
Fd55aD0678E9b90D5f5175d7cE5fD1eBd440309D
```

which can be verified on https://www.rfctools.com/ethereum-address-test-tool.

---

Full code:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const keccak256 = require('keccak256');

var publicKey = {
  pem: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
    'MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEeYRv0S7Zf5CNh5/APxiT6xoY+z521DHT\n' +
    'FgLdUPUP2e/3jkYDuZTbCHP8zEHm7nhG6AUOpJCbTF2J2vWkC1i3Yg==\n' +
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n',
  algorithm: 'EC_SIGN_SECP256K1_SHA256',
  pemCrc32c: { value: '41325621' },
  name: 'PATH-TO-KEY-ON-KMS/cryptoKeyVersions/1',
  protectionLevel: 'HSM'
}

// Export raw public key (without 0x04 prefix)
var x509pem = publicKey.pem;
var x509der = crypto.createPublicKey(x509pem).export({format: 'der', type: 'spki'});
var rawXY = x509der.subarray(-64);
console.log('Raw key: 0x' + rawXY.toString('hex')); // 79846fd12ed97f908d879fc03f1893eb1a18fb3e76d431d31602dd50f50fd9eff78e4603b994db0873fccc41e6ee7846e8050ea4909b4c5d89daf5a40b58b762

// Derive address from raw public key
var hashXY = keccak256(rawXY);
var address = hashXY.subarray(-20).toString('hex').toLowerCase();

// Calculate checksum (expressed as upper/lower case in the address)
var addressHash = keccak256(address).toString('hex');
var addressChecksum = '';
for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++){
    if (parseInt(addressHash[i], 16) > 7) {
        addressChecksum += address[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
        addressChecksum += address[i];
    }
}

console.log('Derived: 0x' + addressChecksum);                       // 0xFd55aD0678E9b90D5f5175d7cE5fD1eBd440309D
console.log('Test:    0xFd55aD0678E9b90D5f5175d7cE5fD1eBd440309D'); // from https://www.rfctools.com/ethereum-address-test-tool using the raw key
```

Answer (score 0):

Google provides public keys encoded in DER format.

To derive an Ethereum Address, one must first obtain the Ethereum public key.

The asn1js library serves as an efficient mechanism for decoding and interpreting the DER-encoded public key data.

It is important to note, as per section 2.2 of RFC 5480, that the initial byte 0x04 signifies an uncompressed key. By removing this initial byte, one can acquire a standard Ethereum public key.

Here's how to decrypt the DER-encoded public key:

```js
import * as asn1js from "asn1js";

decryptPublickeyDerEncoding(input: Buffer) : Buffer {
    /**
     * Before calculating the Ethereum address, we need to get the raw value of the public key.
     * the input returns a DER-encoded X.509 public key
     * asSubjectPublickeyInfo (SPKI), as defined in RFC 5280. 
     * Use an ASN1 library that allows us to define this as a schema as `OBJECT IDENTIFIER `
     * https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2
     */
    const schema = new asn1js.Sequence({
        value: [
            new asn1js.Sequence({ value: [new asn1js.ObjectIdentifier()] }),
            new asn1js.BitString({ name: "objectIdentifier" }),
        ]
    });
    const parsed = asn1js.verifySchema(input, schema);
    if (!parsed.verified) {
        throw new Error(`Publickey: failed to parse. ${parsed.result.error}`);
    }
    const objectIdentifier: ArrayBuffer = parsed.result.objectIdentifier.valueBlock.valueHex;

    /**
     * According to section 2.2 of RFC 5480, the first byte, 0x04 indicates that this is an uncompressed key.
     * We need to remove this byte for the public key to be correct. Once we delete the first byte, we get the
     * raw public key that can be used to calculate our Ethereum address.
     */
    const publickey = objectIdentifier.slice(1); // remove 0x04

    /**
     * Returns the wallet's public key buffer
     */
    return Buffer.from(publickey);
}
```

With the Ethereum public key in hand, you can now compute the Ethereum Address:

```js
publickeyToAddress(input: Buffer) {
    const hash = Buffer.from(keccak256(input), 'hex');
    const address = "0x" + hash.slice(-20).toString('hex');
    return address;
}
```

And there you have it, your Ethereum Address!